# Use "for..of" to iterate through only a section of the array

Tags: arrays, loops, typescript, web

This is my code to iterate through the array.

```
for (let name of group['controls']) {
   //code
}
```

If the length of the group['controls'] array is **X**, how to iterate through **0** to **X-2**?

Comment: You could slice an array: `for (let name of x.slice(0, x.length-2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for..in` and the `for...of` loop will iterate the entire array so from `0` to `length - 1` (or X-1 in your question).

To stop a `for...of` loop to a given index, you have to add a condition inside the loop and call a `break`, like this:

```
for (let index of group['controls']) {
    let name = group['controls'][index];
    if(index == group['controls'].length -2) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Additionnal information:

- `for...in` loop iterate on values: `names` in your examples.
- `for...of` loop iterate on the indexes of the array: `group['controls']` in your example.

Comment: I had to change the questions. There was a mistake in the code.  I wanted the loop through 0 to length - 2. please see the edits.

Comment: I edited the answer. But, it does not change how loops works: it loops through the entire array: from index `0` to index `length - 1`.

Comment: Noted. I guess I can use this one. But I'm open to more methods.

Comment: With a `for...of` loop, I don't see any other way to do it. If you want several way of acheiving your need, you can use a clasic `for` loop or a `while` loop. (But you asked for a `for...of` loop).